# ML tasks not running in parallel

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

**EDITED FOR MORE DETAILS**

I am testing parameters for classifiers, and have about 3k parameter combinations for SVM and 3k for MLP. Therefore, I want to run tests in parallel to streamline the results.

I have a server with 24 cores/48 threads and 128gb of RAM. In order to place various jobs in parallel, I have already tried using multiple workers and multiple executors. I have even used [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). But I always get sequential results, i.e., in my results folder I can see that only one classifier is outputting results and the time it takes to produce results matches a sequential profile.

I tried submitting the same jar multiple times (using `spark-submit`), each testing different parameters; I tried generating all 6k different command combinations to a file and then passing it to gnu parallel, and nothing. Except for adding more executors and changing the resources available per executor, I use the standard spark settings are per download of spark pre-built with hadoop.

As I read in the documentation, each execution should use the same spark context. Is this correct?

Why I don't have parallelism to my tests? What is the ideal combination of workers, executors and resources for each?

**EDIT 2** changed scheduler to FAIR, will post results about this change

**EDIT 3** Fair scheduler made no difference

**PSEUDO-CODE**

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("foo").getOrCreate()
  sparkContext = spark.sparkContext

  //read properties
  //initiate classfier
  //cross validation procedures
  //write results

  spark.stop()
}
```

Comment: Please code code and Spark UI Time Line

Comment: Educated guess: because each job uses all available resources?

Comment: 4gb is enough for each job. So thanks but that is not the issue

Comment: I don't think you got my point. Standalone cluster uses  FIFO scheduler. If all threads (a.k.a cores) are assigned to a single job then you'll get a sequential behavior. But as @T.Gawęda said you should provide additional details. Right now it is not clear which manage you use, how you configure individual jobs, and how you submit.

Comment: @zero323, are the details enough?

Comment: It is late so I could be wrong but, if this is standalone mode, I believe it doesn't support FAIR. Also there is no hint here about the job configuration. So it is not clear how many cores you request per submission.

Comment: Do you get sequential performance if you run two in parallel by hand? Eg: `mysvm arg1 & mysvm arg2 & wait`